# React: Trying to read custom file consistently leads to index.html

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to read a user-selected file in my React app, using the following code:

```
function Entries() {

    async function importEntries() {
        let file = document.getElementById('file-select').files[0];
        let response = await fetch(file);
        let textResponse = await response.text();
        console.log(textResponse);
   }

    return (
        <div className='Entries'>
            <h2>Import entries</h2>
                <label htmlFor='file-select'>Select file:</label>
                <input type='file' name='file' id='file-select' />
                <button onClick={importEntries}>Upload</button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

This is somehow consistently giving me the contents of the index.html file in the public directory of my React app, no matter which file I select.

Anyone knows what is causing this?

Answer (score 0):

use then and catch in [fetch method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

Example :

```
fetch('http://example.com/movies.json')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data));
  .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Comment: I tried that in the first place, but the same thing happened. Also why would it make a difference? Isn't async/await supposed to do exactly the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Replace `<input type='file' name='file' id='file-select' />` to `<input type='file' name='file' id='file-select' onChange={importEntries}/>`

And then replace your `importEntries` method to this:

```
async function importEntries(e) {
        let file = e.target.files[0];

        /* Try this edit */
        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsText(file);
        reader.onload = function() {
            console.log(reader.result);
        };
        reader.onerror = function() {
            console.log(reader.error);
        };
   }
```

I haven't tested the code let me know if this worked.

Comment: Yes, this works! Thanks a lot :) Still, do you understand why my old code yielded such a strange result?

Comment: @StijnKlijn Glad to help. Please upvote this answer. And I am gonna some more information to tell you why your old code didn't work. Add ```console.log(file)``` after ```let file = document.getElementById('file-select').files[0];``` in your old code and tell me what is the output?

Comment: Oops, correction, it did NOT work. I still had a dummy file in my fetch call, that's why it appeared to work. But once i adopt your code I get the same strange thing. The output when doing a console log is this:

File {name: "test.csv", lastModified: 1621963885803, lastModifiedDate: Tue May 25 2021 19:31:25 GMT+0200 (Midden-Europese zomertijd), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 11759, …}

Which is the correct file! However when I read it using fetch, I get the contents of the index.html file in the public directory...

Comment: I have made few edits to my code. Let me know if it works now.

Comment: Turns out that my old code works if I don't use fetch. Instead of that I now use `let file = e.target.files[0];` and then `let textResponse = await file.text();`. Then it works :) Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad that you found a solution

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you're trying to `fetch` this file? As far as I have seen, you can do something like

```
  async function importEntries() {
        let file = document.getElementById('file-select').files[0];
        let textResponse = await file.text();
        console.log(textResponse);
   }
```

or use a `FileReader`.

Also, unrelated, you might want to avoid using `document.getElementById` and `useRef` instead, like so:

```
const fileInputRef = useRef();

  async function importEntries() {
        let file = fileInputRef.current.files[0];
        let textResponse = await file.text();
        console.log(textResponse);
   }

//Later in the code
<input type='file' name='file' ref={fileInputRef} />
```

Comment: I am new to JS and React and have no experience with ways other than fetch. The same goes for the useRef hook, I'm going to read the documentation for that one. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Oh wait, now I get it. I don't need the fetch line at all. It's working now. Thanks :)